# Two-Way Synchronization between Azure SQL and wpf/uwp clients

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, synchronization, azure-sql-database

I have a Azure SQL database, and then clients (UWP and WPF) running SQLite that gets data from the database.

The clients can change the data and it updates the Azure SQL rows and they can insert new items/rows.

My problem is that multiple clients are working at the same time and i would like the client to update as soon as there is a change (insert/update/delete) on the Azure SQL database. Today the user has to press update in order to get latest.

However I not sure how to implement this.

I have been looking into using SQL "Change Tracking" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017and can easily active Change Tracking in Azure on the SQL server and Table, however i cannot find any documentation on how to use this to sync to client in C#, is there some?

Maybe there is a better way of doing this?

Any input is much appreciated.